# How to check whether a stored procedure exists on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm pretty new to PostgreSQL and trying to learn PostgreSQL with the knowledge that I have on MS SQL Server & Oracle. I am looking for an equivalent of the following statement that we can use in MS SQL Server to check whether a Stored procedure exists or not, in **PostgreSQL** where SPName is your stored procedure's name.

```
SELECT 1 FROM sys.procedures WHERE Name = 'SPName')
SELECT 1 FROM sys.procedures WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.SPName')
```

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-routines.html or http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-proc.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc
        JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_catalog.pg_proc.pronamespace = pg_namespace.oid
        WHERE proname = 'proc_name'
            AND pg_namespace.nspname = 'schema_name'
        )
```

If you've not created a specific schema then use `public`(`pg_namespace.nspname = 'public'`)

---

OR

You can create a custom function to do the task like below:

```
create or replace function function_exists (sch text,fun text) returns boolean as
$$
begin
EXECUTE  'select pg_get_functiondef('''||sch||'.'||fun||'''::regprocedure)';
return true;
exception when others then 
return false;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

and use :

```
select function_exists('public','function_name()')
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip @wingedpanther!

Comment: All you need in your function is `PERFORM (sch||'.'||fun)::regprocedure`. The dynamic query is unnecessary, and `pg_get_functiondef()` is not doing anything. Note also that catching an exception basically equates to a `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT`, so I would generally try to avoid it in something this simple.

Comment: For 9.4+, there is the [`to_regprocedure()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) which does almost the same (just check its result with `IS NULL` to find out whether the function exists or not). For just a name test (without function signature) there is the `to_regproc()` function (but that will return `NULL` when the name is ambiguous).

Answer (score 4):

One-liner:

```sql
SELECT to_regproc('schema_name.proc_name') IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   pg_proc JOIN pg_namespace on pg_proc.oid = pg_namespace.oid
  WHERE  pg_proc.proname = 'procedure name'
  and pg_namespace.nspname = 'name'  );
```

Comment: You need to join that to pg_namespace to also check for the schema name

Comment: Thanks for the tip to add namespace, it helped... Followed the scripts given below by @wingedpanther and it worked!